# Use static name for a split chunk of Webpack 4

Tags: webpack

It's webpack 4.1.0
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunks-name

Having this entry:

```
entry: {
    'app': './static/js/app.ts'
}
```

I want to generate a file with the name "vendors.bundle.js". I just want it no matter why. (Had no problems with this while using v3)

So, with this splitChunks setup (omitting not important setup properties):

```
 splitChunks: {
    name: function(){return 'wtf'},
     cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
            name: 'vendor'
        }
    }
}
```

I have "vendor.app.bundle.js"

Having this setup

```
splitChunks: {
    name: function(){return 'wtf'},
    cacheGroups: {
        commons: {}
    }
}
```

wtf.app.bundle.js

I am stuck. How I can avoid using entry name in the split chunk output?